# How to get the row sum of a matrix containg characters with corresponding values from another vector

Tags: r, matrix

Hi I have this column extracted from my data:

```
x <- data.frame(Category=factor(c("xxyyxyxyx", "xxyyyyxyx", "xxyyxyxyy",
           "yxyyxyxyx", "xxyyxyyyx")))
> x
  Category
1 xxyyxyxyx
2 xxyyyyxyx
3 xxyyxyxyy
4 yxyyxyxyx
5 xxyyxyyyx
```

I have to calculate the corresponding row sum resulted from each three charaters in each row so I generate this matrix:

```
xx <- t(apply(x, 1, function(x){strsplit(gsub("([[:alnum:]]{3})", "\\1 ", x), " ")[[1]]}))

> xx

         [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
     [1,] "xxy" "yxy" "xyx"
     [2,] "xxy" "yyy" "xyx"
     [3,] "xxy" "yxy" "xyy"
     [4,] "yxy" "yxy" "xyx"
     [5,] "xxy" "yxy" "yyx"
```

each `xx` cell corresponds to a value given in this vector

```
matval=c("xxy"=3, "yxy"=2, "xyx"=7, "xyy"=5, "yyx"=12, "yyy"= 4)
```

I would like based on the matrix `xx` to add in the matrix `x` a column containing the sum of each row i.e.,

```
x

   Category    RowSum
 1 xxyyxyxyx     12
 2 xxyyyyxyx     14
 3 xxyyxyxyy     10
 4 yxyyxyxyx     11
 5 xxyyxyyyx     17
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the key/value index to replace the values in 'xx' and get the `rowSums`

```
x$RowSum <- rowSums(`dim<-`(matval[xx], dim(xx)))
```

---

The 'xx' can also be created with `strsplit`

```
 do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(x$Category), "(?<=.{3})", perl = TRUE))
```

Comment: very neat. I was about to suggest faffing around with `match`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution ! If `matval` is a data.frame i.e,matval=data.frame(cate=c("xxy", "yxy", "xyx", "xyy", "yyx", "yyy"),
                  val=c(3, 2,7, 5, 12, 4))

Comment: the same result can be obtained? If Yes can you please precise me how?

Comment: @sdhaoui  Try by creating a named vector `matval1 <- setNames(matval$val, matval$cate)` and then use `matval1` in the code

Answer (score 3):

**1)** `matval[xx]` will give the individual values which can then be shaped back into a matrix and summed:

```
transform(x, RowSum = rowSums(array(matval[xx], dim(xx))))
```

giving:

```
   Category RowSum
1 xxyyxyxyx     12
2 xxyyyyxyx     14
3 xxyyxyxyy     10
4 yxyyxyxyx     11
5 xxyyxyyyx     17
```

**2)** An alternative which computes the result directly from `x` without computing `xx` first is the following.  It extracts each three characters and applies `matval[...]` to each such extract and then sums the resulting matrix.

```
library(gsubfn)

transform(x, RowSums = 
   colSums(strapply(paste(Category), "...", s ~ matval[s], simplify = TRUE)))
```

**Note:** Another way to compute `xx` is to insert a space after every third character, read it into a data frame and convert that to a matrix.

```
as.matrix(read.table(text = gsub("(...)", "\\1 ", x$Category)))
```

or read it in using `read.fwf` based on 3 fixed width fields of 3 characters each:

```
as.matrix(read.fwf(textConnection(paste(x$Category)), rep(3, 3)))
```

or using `substring`:

```
from <- seq(1, 9, 3)
to <- from + 3 - 1
t(sapply(x$Category, substring, from, to))
```